# Is there any work around for Sikuli IDE image replacement?

Tags: sikuli, jython-2.7, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I am using Sikulix for UI testing, the problem is that when ever there are changes in UI I need to replace all the images which got changed using the IDE and I need to again describe the actions ( accuracy, click position) which is becoming a sort of overhead in my case. Is there any work around by which I can simply replace the new UI images in the project folder with the same old name ( It wont work directly as the new coordinates might be different + the new image should be of same resolution that of older one)

PS: I have completely understood that sikuli works at pixel level, but still curious to find out if any one has found a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will need to recreate the images. What could make it a bit easier, is if you had more descriptive names than the ones generated by Sikuli IDE automatically. Keep in mind these are just image files stored on your PC. If you have names like `button1.png`, `button1.png`, etc.., it will make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not work for you depending on your project development:

In my case, the changes that occur at times reduces the image similarity from say 0.9 defined to ~0.7. Now, rather than going ahead to replace the image with a totally new image where i would have to manipulate the offsets as well now, I capture the same region image at 0.7 similarity and replace it. You can easily create a script for this and even integrate it into your project. Use find to figure out the matching region and capture to take the screenshot of the area. The image caught using this way will now again match at 100% for you also, you have rid yourself from the headache of adjusting the targetoffset. Hope this helps.